# Python - Local variable referenced before assignment error - reading a CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have the following Python 2.7 code. The aim is to read the csv file and run through the script for each row in the CSV file.

The CSV file looks like this (no headers, all filenames in column A - one file name per row, not comma separated)

```
ftp_abc_REFRESH_a
ftp_dep_a
```

The script works for the first file, but fails on the second file with the following error:

```
timestamp  = oupload.stat(file).st_atime
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

The script:

```
def myscript(ofile):  

    import time
    import pysftp 
    import sys
    import os
    from datetime import datetime
    import calendar
    import zipfile
    import re

    oupload = pysftp.Connection(host="hostbcd", username="admin", password="abcs")

    d = datetime.utcnow()
    unixtime=calendar.timegm(d.utctimetuple())

    month = datetime.now().strftime("%m")


    string = ofile+month+".*\.txt$"

    possibleFiles = oupload.listdir("/")
    for filename in possibleFiles:
            filedate = re.search(string, filename)
            if filedate:
                file = filename

    timestamp  = oupload.stat(file).st_atime  
    #if timestamp > unixtime - 54050 - 30 days
    if timestamp != unixtime:
        newtime=unixtime + 1800
        abmfile='filename_'
        zipname = abmfile+str(newtime)+'.sync.zip'
        create_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        oupload.get(file,file)
        oupload.close()
        newfilename = abmfile+str(newtime)+'.sync' 
        os.rename(file, newfilename)
        create_zip.write(newfilename)
        create_zip.close()

    else: 
        print "No files found"

import csv
with open("data.csv", 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for row in reader:
        ofile = row[0]
        result = myscript(ofile)
```

Comment: have you checked that the line `file = filename` does run? I would suggest an initial value for file, assign it before the `for filename in possibleFiles:` loop, and check if it changed after the loop

Comment: you dont have a variable `file` did you mean `ofile`?

Answer (score 0):

The error shows you pretty much everything :
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment`

This means you are trying to use something that has not been set earlier.

The only moment you would initialize `file` is into your if-statement `if filedate`. You are not passing the condition, hence the error and the un-initialiazed `file` object.

Comment: I am slightly confused as I am setting the file variable before the error which happens on this line:  "timestamp  = oupload.stat(file).st_atime" - How would I re-write this? Thanks

Comment: @NickEdwards that `file` only gets initialized `if filedate`, think about what happens if `bool(filedate) == False`

Comment: As far as I am concerned, you are trying to do_things to a `file` variable, that hasn't been set earlier.

What I see is, you do init `oupload`, `d`, (...), `possibleFiles`, `filedate`, and **possibly, if-and-only-if filedate exists** (meaning `is not None`), `file`.

What is happening, if I follow your code correctly, is that you don't find the date you're seeking. So your if-statement does not fill the `file` variable.

I suggest you create an exception case `if file is None` that would do whatever is needed that stops the function correctly, and allows your script to continue.